# Xamarin Loading Overlay Not Showing

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a longish running operation that I want to run synchronously (I will look at async later on).

I am using the overlay code from here - http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/standard_controls/popovers/display_a_loading_message

Here is my test code -

```
    public override void ViewDidAppear (bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidAppear (animated);

        loadingOverlay = new LoadingOverlay (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
        View.Add (loadingOverlay);

        int i = 0;
        while (i < 5000)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
            i++;
        }

        loadingOverlay.Hide ();
    }
```

But the initial overlay does not show, only the Hide animation after the while loop completes?

I can produce a hack / workaround like so -

```
    public override void ViewDidAppear (bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidAppear (animated);

        loadingOverlay = new LoadingOverlay (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
        View.Add (loadingOverlay);

        NSTimer nstimer = NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer (1, () => {

            int i = 0;
            while (i < 5000) {
                Console.WriteLine (i);
                i++;
            }

            loadingOverlay.Hide ();
        });
    }
```

But could someone please explain to me why this is happening, and how to write the code correctly so IOS draws the overlay to screen before it begins the loop.

Comment: Your first example is blocking the UI thread.  The second example runs NSTimer on a background thread, so it does not block the UI.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that Jason, but is there any other way to tell IOS to update the UI Thread after the overlay addition before it blocks? or is this the best workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're blocking the UI thread, which you should never do. Any long running operation should run in the background thread, even if you want to process it in a synchronous way.

With Xamarin.iOS alpha (supporting async/await), your code would look like this:

```
public async override void ViewDidAppear (bool animated)
{
    base.ViewDidAppear (animated);

    loadingOverlay = new LoadingOverlay (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
    View.Add (loadingOverlay);

    await Task.Factory.StartNew (() => {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 5000)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
            i++;
        }
    });

    loadingOverlay.Hide ();
}
```

If you don't have access to `async/await`, you can achieve the same result with:

```
    Task.Factory.StartNew (() => {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 5000)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
            i++;
        }
    }).ContinueWith(task => InvokeOnMainThread(() => { loadingOverlay.Hide(); }));
```

but it's less nice (also, check the closing braces, I just typed this code)

Comment: Thanks @StephaneDelcroix.  I arrived at non await version -
}).ContinueWith(task => InvokeOnMainThread(() => { loadingOverlay.Hide(); }));
Please feel free to update your answer if this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Add [this Component](http://components.xamarin.com/view/btprogresshud/) to your application and be done with it. No need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: as it happens, the reason I ended up asking this question and writing this test code is that I was using that component and it was producing the same issue with a Show(..) - loop - ShowSuccessWithStatus(), only the ShowSuccessWithStatus() is shown.  So I removed the component from the Q.